# How can I show the icons when I scroll down in the page?

Tags: html, css

I want to show the divs where the icons are located when I scroll down to that section of the page with a fade effect from bottom-to-top. How can I do that ONLY with CSS?

---

```css
img{
    height: 80px;
}
.row{
    padding: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 60px;background-color: darkblue;color: wheat;">
        <p>Nav example</p>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 800px;background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/08/00/31/office-1081807_960_720.jpg');background-size: cover;">
    </div>
    <div class="list-icons" style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="row" style="background-color: lemonchiffon">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-456/500/global-business-256.png" alt="">
                <p>Relation</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-456/500/processing-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Diagnose</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-456/500/target-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Plan</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="background-color:burlywood">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-456/500/management-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Action</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-startup-10/50/16-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Feedback</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see how this can be done using CSS alone - is there any way that CSS can 'sense' when an element comes into view?

Comment: @AHaworth is right, you'd need JavaScript to detect the scrolling, I've added an example ```ONLY with CSS``` as requested, but because of this the animation will begin whenever the page is loaded, not on scroll.

Comment: That's the point, i need it only with css.

Comment: It can't be done only with CSS - sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly on what you're attempting to do, this will accomplish a *fade effect from bottom-to-top*. Adjust the `.animated` durations as needed.

*Only option below with JUST CSS, On Scroll requires JS*

https://jsfiddle.net/y1gfmcrh/

**CSS**

```
img {
  height: 80px;
}

.row {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
        transform: translate3d(0,40px,0)
    }

    to {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
    }

    to {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        opacity: 1
    }
}

.animated {
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both
}

.animatedFadeInUp {
    opacity: 0
}

.fadeInUp {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: fadeInUp;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 60px;background-color: darkblue;color: wheat;">
        <p>Nav example</p>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 800px;background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/08/00/31/office-1081807_960_720.jpg');background-size: cover;">
    </div>
    <div class="list-icons" style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="row" style="background-color: lemonchiffon">
          <div class="animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp col-sm-4">
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-456/500/global-business-256.png" alt="">
            <p>Relation</p>
          </div>
          <div class="animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp col-sm-4">
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-456/500/processing-128.png" alt="">
            <p>Diagnose</p>
          </div>
          <div class="animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp col-sm">
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-456/500/target-128.png" alt="">
            <p>Plan</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="background-color:burlywood">
            <div class="animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp col-sm-6">
                <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-456/500/management-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Action</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp col-sm">
                <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-startup-10/50/16-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Feedback</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
img {
  height: 80px;
}

.row {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
        transform: translate3d(0,40px,0)
    }

    to {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
    }

    to {
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        opacity: 1
    }
}

.animated {
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both
}

.animatedFadeInUp {
    opacity: 0
}

.fadeInUp {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: fadeInUp;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 60px;background-color: darkblue;color: wheat;">
        <p>Nav example</p>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 800px;background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/08/00/31/office-1081807_960_720.jpg');background-size: cover;">
    </div>
    <div class="list-icons" style="text-align: center;">
        <div class="row" style="background-color: lemonchiffon">
          <div class="animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp col-sm-4">
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-456/500/global-business-256.png" alt="">
            <p>Relation</p>
          </div>
          <div class="animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp col-sm-4">
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-456/500/processing-128.png" alt="">
            <p>Diagnose</p>
          </div>
          <div class="animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp col-sm">
            <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-456/500/target-128.png" alt="">
            <p>Plan</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="background-color:burlywood">
            <div class="animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp col-sm-6">
                <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-456/500/management-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Action</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animated animatedFadeInUp fadeInUp col-sm">
                <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-startup-10/50/16-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Feedback</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sadly I see no fade effect on the snippet example

Comment: hmm really? I can run the code snippet and see it on my end, it's the icons on the bottom of the page. Fade-In Effect with icons appearing to fade in from bottom up into position.

Comment: Hi, I can't see where you alter the CSS so the icons fade in when the icons come into the viewport

Comment: Each div class now has "animated, animatedFadeInUp, fadeInUp" added to OP's code. Then the css is manipulated to allow the effect of the icons based on ```.animated``` duration selections. OP has only ```img``` and ```.row``` in CSS, I've added all others.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn´t work on the snippet. I tested it on VSC and it didn´t work either.

Comment: It's hard to see in the snippet as because the window is so small you need to scroll down to notice the effect before the animation is done, I'd recommend copying and pasting the code into an outside editor with a bigger result window. Added JSFiddle to answer, as well as increased the duration to 5 seconds.